# Azure - IP filter depending on the database

Tags: sql, security, azure, filter, ip

I have a Azure application that use different databases of different servers. This databases are independent, and each sector of my application uses only one database.
I try make a IP filter. This filter must identify the solicitant's ip, and allow access each database or not depending this filter. This give me a way for allow access to A and not to B for a IP, access to B and not to A for another IP, full access for another diferent IP... using the security of Azure.
It's this possible?

Thanks, I wait a answer!

PD: sorry for my horrible english!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to SQL Azure hosted databases, you can use Database-Level Firewall settings, which are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj553530.aspx).

> Create a database-level firewall rule by using the
>   sp_set_database_firewall_rule stored procedure. Add a new firewall
>   setting for Internet-based connections by specifying a unique name in
>   the name parameter of the sp_set_database_firewall_rule stored
>   procedure. Specify the lowest desired IP address in that range with
>   the start_ip_address parameter and the highest desired IP address in
>   that range with the end_ip_address parameter. The name parameter is of
>   the nvarchar data type and the start_ip_address and the end_ip_address
>   parameters are of the varchar data type.
>
> Similarly, you can enable connection attempts from Windows Azure by
>   using the sp_set_database_firewall_rule stored procedure with the
>   parameters start_ip_address and end_ip_address equal to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
But as far I have understood the basic level locking SQL only limit access to external applications that try to connect. By allowing all connections Azure services, whatever the IP that attack on my application, the IP contacting with database is that of the application, not the client (always with IP from application). Thus, I don't know limiting this access.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you'll have already found a solution to this given its a couple of months old now, but just in-case...

Assuming I'm understanding correctly, you have a bunch of clients communicating to your application server, which in turn queries one of many database servers.  The firewall suggested by mellamokb isn't an option as the client isn't actually hitting the database, and so what's needed has to sit on the application server.

Selecting the connection string used to access the/a database based on the client's IP address is probably what you're after here.  If you also need to lock the database down using its native security, you will need to create a named user account for each of your clients.

Alternatively, you could investigate [Federations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh597452.aspx) on the Azure SQL Database and use either the client's IP address or a similar identifier as the distribution key.